# CKEditor cktext_area only shows up when refreshing page (Rails 4/Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, ckeditor

My local version runs CKEditor fine.
**Edit: Local version does the same thing.**

It's runs on heroku as well, but when I first load my create blog post page, the cktext_area simply shows up as a normal text_area box. When I refresh the page, the ck_textarea shows up like it is supposed to.

I'm not sure why this is happening.

This is using rails 4.

Here's my application layout

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
        <% if notice %>
          <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
        <% end %>
        <% if alert %>
          <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
        <% end %>
        <%= yield %>
        <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require_tree .
```

And my blog create form

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :size=>'50' %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.cktext_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Where are you loading JS in your application layout?  I have found that loading it at the bottom of the page (after all elements are defined) ensures the elements are available when JS loads.

Comment: Steve, added my files. I'm not sure where to load the js to make it work. When I loaded it at the bottom I got an error.

Comment: Try moving the `javascript_include_tag` line immediately after the footer line in your layout (before closing off the container).

Comment: Doing that works, though it sorta breaks my bootstrap dropdown menu in my header...sometimes. Like, it freezes until I refresh... I'm not well versed in javascript :(

Comment: It shouldn't break anything.  I wonder if you are loading bootstrap or some other JS twice by mistake.

Comment: I don't think it's being loaded twice. My JS is only loaded on application layout. I found out it's a turbolinks issue. The problem goes away when I remove turbolinks, but I'd like to find a solution that includes turbolinks if possible.

Comment: Yes I saw you resolved.  If you still want to pursue fixing, you could update your OP to include your JS manifest file.  The other possibility is that your page is loading super slow and the JS is not loaded when you try the header functionality.  You could move the JS load right before your footer line so at least you can see that JS is loaded when the footer loads (JS loads synchronously so the footer will not load until JS is fully loaded in this configuration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>OK. Well. This isn't a complete solution, but removing turbolinks solves this issue. I certainly don't need turbolinks for my project, but it would eventually be nice to find a solution that works including turbolinks.</strike>

removed `//= require turbolinks` from application.js

It would seem CKEditor doesn't play nice with turbolinks. Instead of disabling turbolinks, I simply added a `data: { 'no-turbolink' => true }` to any link that contained a ckeditor.

For example, in my header I had a link to create a new blog post:

```
<%= link_to "Create New Blog Post", new_article_path, data: { 'no-turbolink'=>true} %>
```

This solved it for me, without completely removing turbolinks.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, but may be it will help someone.

The problem is that ckeditor isn't initialized after visiting a turbolinks link. So the solution is to reinitialize ckeditor every time turbolinks loads pages.

This could be done using [turbolinks callback](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events) `turbolinks:load` (page:load for old versions)

The second problem is that `turbolinks:load` fires every time even on document ready event. So I have to check somehow if ckeditor is initializes or I'll get `The editor instance ... is already attached to the provided element.`

The final code will be:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.ckeditor:visible').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (!CKEDITOR.instances[id]) {
       CKEDITOR.replace(id);
    }});
});
```